# Getting ascii bytes from text field in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, byte, ascii, bytea

There's a text field that we want converted to bytes using ascii in PostgreSQL.

Example:

> "table" = t:116*1 (1 being first position) + a:97*2(2 being second
>   position) + b: 99*3, etc.

Doing `select ascii([text field])` only returns the ascii bytes for the first letter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want a `bytea` value corresponding to the string's byte sequence, you can use:

```
SELECT convert_to('åbçd€','SQL_ASCII')
```

If this is isn't quite what you're looking for, you can convert to a set of codepoints, and from there, you can do what you want with it:

```
SELECT ascii(c) FROM regexp_split_to_table('åbçd€','') s(c)
```

Note that these are very different in the way that they handle non-ASCII characters. Assuming a UTF8-encoded database, `convert_to('å','SQL_ASCII')` will give you multiple UTF8 code units, while `ascii('å')` returns a single Unicode codepoint.

Comment: I did select name, regexp_split_to_array(name, '')) from my_table and now it looks like this: {a,b,c,d,e}. Is it possible to split that up further so that each letter gets it's own row?

Comment: The query in my answer (using `regexp_split_to_table()`) will do that